# 400 Error when Trying to submit rails form via AJAX

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, rails-activestorage

Here's the setup:

- Very simple form, just a `name` field, plus two ActiveStorage attachment fields `square_image` and `landscape_image`.
- Both fields have `direct_upload: true` set.
- If *all* form fields are filled out, including the files, the submit work exactly right, no problem.
- *However*, if you fill out only the `name` field, leaving *any* of the file fields blank, I get an `invalid_request` every time.

**This only happens in Safari**.

The debug logs from nginx reveal `client prematurely closed stream: only 548 out of 953 bytes of request body received`.

It doesn't seem to be an nginx issue, because I get a similar experience locally via `pow` (the connection just hangs for a long time, presumably because `pow` is waiting for the data that never arrives).

Has anyone else experienced this, or have any ideas about how to debug this? I can't figure out where to go from here.

- Rails 5.2.0
- Safari 11.1 (13605.1.33.1.2)

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed a bug in webkit. It has allegly been fixed but at this point in time, the bug still affects Safari. https://trac.webkit.org/changeset/230963/webkit